# Inject a gateway and a service together to each other/circular dependency

Tags: nestjs

I have one `Gateway` and another `Service` in the same module, the gateway needs access to the service to work, but I also want to inject the gateway into the service which needs the reference to send events directly to the clients.

Making the injection only in one way works, but not in both ways.

Is this possible or what would be the preferred solution? Keeping only one way injection and adding the other as a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try resolving this using [Circular Dependencies](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)?

Generally you just need to use `forwardRef` in both injectable classes

```js
@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CommonService))
    private commonService: CommonService,
  ) {}
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CatsService))
    private catsService: CatsService,
  ) {}
}
```